# Timeouts in Kynetx apps?

Tags: krl

I was wondering if there's an undocumented way to set a timeout on a dataset/datasource request? I just realized that when the API that my rule uses goes down, there isn't a way to catch it after n seconds and give the user an error message and/or notify me about downtime.

Comment: Does the API that you are using return a 400 error or some other error code when it goes down?

Comment: The night that this happened their whole site would hang for a really long time. I think they probably handle certain errors with 404s or something like that, but this was sort of a fluke. That could even happen with really long DNS lookups too I guess.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a way to specify a timeout.  I will suggest this as an enhancement

Comment: thx! I wonder if it could be worked into a "postlude", like "} timedout {" or something like that.